# GitLab Dependency Scan Requires package-lock.json in Source Code for Execution

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, node-modules

I want to run a GitLab CI pipeline that utilizes vulnerability scanning (GitLab Ultimate). The issue is that I need to create the package-lock.json file during the build stage. As far as I understand, the job will not execute if the file does not exist in the repository at the time of pipeline execution. Can someone assist me with this? :)

**NodeJS repo for building NPM packages. (not for building docker images)**

using Artifact block did not help me in the process...

Comment: Why not commit a lock file locally and push it?

Comment: As an organization we dont want to commit a lock file to the repo.
We want to make sure that the lock file is a result of the npm build of the current pipeline run/

Comment: And how about rejecting pushes with a lock-file and still have it under version control later on when you do the pipelining? That would reflect the npm build requirements you have and would not block GitLab from running the vulnerabilities scan you're looking for and which works according to your knowledge? Have you tried this at least, so you can start to argue about the process (current and next) rather than only seeing issues?

Comment: @hakre, I just did what you said, and it worked. However, I thought there could be a more elegant way to achieve it. I also found a thread about the issue at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/284078. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Your organization policies are going to make it hard to have a reproducible build

Comment: The builtin node-js SAST scanning [only requires `package.json` to exist](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml#L164-165), not a lockfile. Do you not commit a `package.json`? Or do you mean dependency scanning? Which scanning template are you using?

Comment: @MrZorkiPongi: You're welcome. Don't forget to [edit] the question and add all the clarifications that are so far only in comments. That will improve your question and IMHO it should be en-par with the elegance you're striving for with your build, so that it communicates well.

Comment: @sytech yes i meant dependency scanning,  adding now the clarifications and changes to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `rules:` for the scanning job to remove the need for the lock file to exist. For example, the job `gemnasium-dependency_scanning` from the builtin dependency scan template normally [requires a lock file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/70654c7306d007eb6bdfa970747f682a7f556718/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml#L58-68) (such as `**/yarn.lock` or `package.lock.json`) to exist. But this can be overwritten. Additionally, you can add dependencies on other jobs, like a job that produces your lockfile in order to ensure the generated lockfile is present for the scanning job (by default scanning jobs ignore artifacts).

```yaml
include:
  - template: Jobs/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

generate-lockfile:
  # ...
  stage: build
  # this is just an example...
  # update `script:` and `artifacts:` to your needs
  script:
    - yarn install --mode update-lockfile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - yarn.lock

gemnasium-dependency_scanning:
  rules:  # override rules to not require lockfile to be committed
    - when: on_success
  dependencies: [generate-lockfile]  # download lockfile artifacts
```

This will ensure the scanning job is created in the pipeline even if you don't commit a lockfile and will also enable the job to download artifacts from a job where you produce your lockfile.
Just change the `generate-lockfile` job to whatever is necessary for generating your lockfile and expose it as an artifact.

---

Of course, you probably want to be committing a lock file to begin with, but that's beside the point in this question, I suppose.